# Scrollable container beneath variable height

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to lay out some CSS to build a site to look like a fairly typical desktop app type layout:

[image: Wireframe of desired layout]

I've almost got it all working, however I'm having problems getting the scrollable panel to stick to the bottom of the viewport and display with a scrollbar instead of overflowing off the page.

The HTML and CSS I have so far is:

**HTML**

```
<nav></nav> <!-- Fixed height header -->
<aside></aside> <!-- Fixed height/width sidebar -->
<main><!-- Right content area container -->
    <div class="top"></div> <!-- Right side top adjustable height panel -->
    <div class="toolbar"></div> <!-- Fixed height toolbar -->
    <div class="content"></div> <!-- Scrollable panel -->
</main>
```

**CSS**

```
nav {
  width 100%;
  height: 40px;
}

aside {
  width: 260px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 40px;
  bottom: 0;
}

main {
  position: absolute;
  left: 260px;
  top: 40px;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
}

.top {
  position: relative;
  right: 0;
  left: 0;
  min-height: 200px;
}

.toolbar {
  height: 30px;
  position: relative;
  right: 0;
  left: 0;
}

.content {
  position: relative;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  overflow: auto;
  right: 0;
}
```

With the CSS above, the scrollable panel will not stay within the confines of the viewport and display a scrollbar. I'm hoping to find a javascript-less solution (it's all living in an angular app so I'd like to avoid relying on javascript for positioning if I can avoid it)

Comment: use the position:fixed for scrollable pannel and overflow:auto

Answer (score 1):

You can create this layout easily using calc.

http://jsfiddle.net/q18k57zr/

```
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
}

header {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 40px;
  background: #333;
}

aside {
  position: fixed;
  top: 40px;
  left: 0;
  width: 200px;
  height: 100%;
  background: #666;
}

main {
  position: relative;
  top: 40px;
  width: calc(100% - 200px);
  height: calc(100% - 40px);
  margin: 0 0 0 200px;
  background: #999;
}

.section-top {
  height: 100px;
}

.section-toolbar {
  height: 40px;
  background: #fff;
}

.section-scrollable {
  height: calc(100% - 140px);
  overflow-y: scroll;
  background: #ccc;
  padding: 20px;
}
```

This is clearly just some demo code.  Not intended to be used, but you'll get the idea. There are a bit of magic numbers in there, but this can easily be set up as variables with Sass/LESS and just do a bit of math.

Comment: I had considered this approach but not tried it yet. The only problem I see is the top container is variable height - I couldn't find a way to get another elements height with calc()

Comment: Oh I understand now...  I thought the top container was a set height.  You are wanting the top container height to vary based on what is inside it, correct?  In that case, this wouldn't work.  I think you can use flexbox for this, but I am not a fan of flexbox personally.  Better support would be to just use a bit of javascript to get the height of the top container and do a bit of math for the bottom container.  But thats not a 100% css solution obviously.

Comment: Yeah, I think you're right - seems like I'll have to learn flexbox. I'd have done this in JS already, but because it's an angular app it's a bit finicky with JavaScript Dom manipulation. Seems like the answer is an angular directive or flexbox. Thanks for taking the time to answer.

Comment: Ya, thats one of the most annoying things to me about Angular.  If you don't have to worry about certain browsers, I'd say go the flexbox route.  Good luck!